# Recurrent events in iCalendar not working

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to add recurring events to my personal calendar via .ics, The client imports and adds the first event to the calendar but doesn't create other repeating events.

I'm actually creating a recurring event which happens daily, below is the sample of my .ics file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//com.denhaven2/NONSGML ri_cal gem//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111103T182116Z
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111104T130000Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111104T103000Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111103T182116Z
LAST-MODIFIED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111103T182116Z
UID:availability_slot42@chronus.com
DESCRIPTION:Availability slot from mentoring program
SUMMARY:Mentoring Slot
ORGANIZER:iitm_mentor3@chronus.com
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;WKST=MO;
EXRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA,SU
LOCATION:Daily withoiut until
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like the problem is with the client s/w, not your ics file.

Your code above validates at http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/
and loads and recurs fine in google calendar.
see https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=jpkdu09olie8uveopl72oguj2s%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Australia/Sydney

Cross test on some more other calendar clients to verify.

Comment: Can you please check this link as well !
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029149/weekly-recurring-events-in-icalendar