# Weekly recurring events in iCalendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have pasted below my ics file for a recurring event, It is a weekly recurring event, this recurs on monday, tuesday, wednesday. I checked the syntax, It seems to be fine. Is there anything wrong in this.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//com.denhaven2/NONSGML ri_cal gem//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111106T175719Z
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111110T183000Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111110T160000Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111106T175719Z
LAST-MODIFIED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20111106T175719Z
UID:availability_slot330@xyz.com
DESCRIPTION:Availability slot from mentoring program
SUMMARY:Mentoring Slot
ORGANIZER:iitm_mentor2@xyz.com
RRULE;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE;WKST=MO:FREQ=WEEKLY
EXRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA,SU
LOCATION:Church park
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you done to assess whether something is wrong?
What errors have you  experienced?

Did you validate it ?
http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/

have you tried to load into any ical clients (google calendar,outllok, thunderbird etc) - what do they do?

Have you checked against the spec for examples:

http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545.txt
has examples like this
 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=4;BYDAY=-1SU;UNTIL=19730429T070000Z

Possibly the weekly should follow the  RRULE immediately 
your exrule should be superfluous if BYDAY is there.

Comment: Yes, Actually the FREQ value should follow the RRULE, That was the mistake, Thanks for the help.